# Find all possible values of the determinant of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am given that $A$ is an $m$ by $m$ matrix and that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are both filled with integer values. How can I find all possible values of the determinant of $A$?

I tried solving this by stating $\det(AA^{-1})=1$. Then $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$ and $\det(A)= \det(A^{-1})^{-1}$. However, when simplified, this just gives me $\det(A)= \det(A)$.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of determinant (either by the Leibniz formula or Laplace expansion), it's easy to see that $\det(A^{-1})$ is an integer.  From your question, its multiplicative inverse $\det(A^{-1})^{-1}$ also has to be an integer, so only $1$ and $-1$ can satisfy this.